# disable row add on mouse drag down

Tags: handsontable

In my handsontable, I want to disable the auto row add function when user drag down the mouse cursor but I want to have row add function when  user goes through the context menu. To achieve this, I have set

```
      minSpareRows :0,
       minSpareCols :0
```

But it did not work. Is there way to disable row adding functionality when user drag down the mouse but still enable same functionality for other purpose like from context menu

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for, I think, is the `fillHandle:false` option. It will disable the drag down with the mouse while allowing you to keep the functionality in the context menu.

Comment: No.. I do not want to disable the drag down but I do want to disable add row at the end of the row when we drag down the mouse.

Comment: What do you mean "drag down the mouse"? Dragging down doesn't add a row. You can only add a row if you hit enter at the last row.

Comment: of course it does add row when you drag down the mouse . try drag down the mouse cursor towards the end of the row for this fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b93kaa4v/)

Comment: what browser are you using? what OS? I have no idea how you're making that happen

Comment: Ok, when you said "I do nott want to disable the dragdown" you should've said "I ONLY want to disable the drag down on the last row". If you drag downt he mouse cursor on any cell it does nothing. If you drag down the FILL HANDLE it will create new rows at the bottom. Miscommunication sucks, sorry this happened. My suggestion would be to try what the github issues say. If that doesn't work well enough, maybe you could disable the fill handle only on the cells of the last row.